# How to create a UDP jumbogram in Netty and/or Java?

Tags: java, network-programming, udp, netty

I'm researching sending a UDP Jumbogram(in this case, just over 2^16 bytes) on a internal network that uses IPv6. Is this possible in Netty, or the Java sockets library?

Answer (score 0):

UDP or TCP a packet cannot be over 64k size. Jumbograms or jumbo packets are in network(for physical layer transmission) layer level terms . if they are supported by all the link node between the sender and receiver they can send 64k packet along the link . But in the application level u cannot create more than 64k size.

Refer : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbogram